# Create VSTO 3.0 Outlook Add In to run on office 2003/2007/2010(x32 and x64)

Tags: outlook, vsto, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-2003

Is it possible to create an add in that works on all office versions?

I searched the msdn and different forums but there is nothing specific about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult if you use VSTO, because you'll need to deploy/assure different runtime libraries. [See the VSTO entry in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSTO), not to speak of different development and test platforms (which you may already have, if you aim for it).

There's a [MSDN Blog from Mary Lee](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/10/05/installing-office-2007-vsto-3-0-solutions-on-computers-with-office-2010.aspx) the migration of  2007 to 2010 projects.

Please see also this blog from Andrew Whitechapel: [Can you build one add-in for multiple versions of Office?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/06/15/can-you-build-one-add-in-for-multiple-versions-of-office.aspx)

From a pragmatical point of view ("time-to-market"), you may consider the use of a third-party-tool ([www.add-in-express.com](http://www.add-in-express.com)), which allows the creation of version-independent add-ins.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes it is hard to make a VSTO add in to work on all versions. I think the best solution is to create a shared COM add in. I'm working on one right now and it works on all office versions.

Comment: can u tell me how to create shared com addin. because i facing same problm